# Sorting coordinates of a shape's outline

Tags: python

So let's say I have the points of this shape's outline:
[image]

Now, these points aren't sorted. What I want to do is turning `[B, E, H, M, P, ...]` into `[A, B, C, D, E, ...].`

I tried to find the top-left point (A) and then go from it on and on. I faled in cases like this one:
[image]

I don't want to use libraries like OpenCV, but write the algorithm myself. Any help?

Comment: The general case for this can be nasty depending on what types of shapes you allow.  I'd use openCV find contours and one of their extra vertex removal techniques.

Comment: @Pete I don't want to use openCV. The type is tuple of two integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612862/minimize-polygon-vertices

Comment: https://algorist.com/problems/Simplifying_Polygons.html