# Biggest distance between two points in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have an array with **CGPoints** (wrapped with **NSValues**). How can I get the two points which are most distant from each other. I mean the **distance between these two points is the biggest**? I can just check every two points but that does not look efficient. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Naively? Test the distances for each combination of points.

Comment: I just found a good duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618398/given-a-set-of-points-how-do-i-find-the-two-points-that-are-farthest-from-each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are not too many points (up to 1000, but if intensive, around 100), use the naive brute-force method O(n<sup>2</sup>).

I haven't read the details, but the biggest distance probably is computable in O(nlog n) with [convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) + [rotating caliper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers).