# Maximum area triangle from intersection of two triangles

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, graphics

I am trying to develop an algorithm to find out maximum area triangle (co ordinates) from intersection of two or more triangles whose coordinates are not much deviated form each other( with all edges cases)

For example: Triangle A with co ordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)  For triangle B x1 is shrinked by dx1 , y1 is shrinked by dy1, x3 is shrinked by dx3, y3 is shrinked by dy3.
For triangle C x2 is shrinked by dx2 , y2 is shrinked by dy2, x3 is shrinked by dx3, y3 is shrinked by dy3.

Now task to is to find a triangle or coordinates of triangle, such that all of the three triangles can 
be reduced to that.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621364/how-to-find-largest-triangle-in-convex-hull-aside-from-brute-force-search

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I dont think above link answers my question

Comment: then please describe how what you want is different from that link.

Comment: am I missing something or just too sober but intersection of two triangles is not a triangle area unless some specified conditions are met ... so please clarify your case a bit more for us not so bright ... I think image would be best ... (post it somewhere and add link so someone with rep can copy it here)

Comment: @Spektre : the way I understand it is that the OP wants to find the largest possible triangle within the polygon defined by the intersection of the two triangles. That's what the link I mentioned does. But apparently my understanding was wrong, so waiting for feedback from the OP.

Comment: @Spektre I have updated the ques with a example. I hope it will help in better understanding

Comment: @ambude that is even more unclear then before add specific example with coordinates or image of input and wanted output example