# Largest simplex in convex hull of points in n dimensions

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given a convex hull C of a set of points in n dimensions, is there a known algorithm (apart from checking all possibilities) that finds the n+1 corner points of a simplex with the largest volume that is completely in C?

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621364/353337) for the same question about polygons/triangles.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubtful, since the problem has a fixed parameter intractability result:
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2006.05.006