# Finding the largest area isosceles triangle in a convex set

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have an object in an image as a binary mask. This object can be described as a convex set. I would like to find 3 points that define an **isosceles** triangle (two equal sides) with the greatest area that is fully contained inside the convex set. In particular, I am interested in a **non** brute force approach. The three vertices of the triangle can be anywhere, inside the convex set or on the edges of the set. I have seen a similar question answered for a general triangle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621913/14431710).

I have tried applying the brute force approach.

Comment: Re: "a modification of the algorithm where we check if norm(AB) = norm(AC) as an additional requirement for each tuple of points would not yield the optimal solution": Indeed, it might not yield *any* "solution"; there's no guarantee that some three vertices define an isosceles triangle.

Comment: Do the three points need to be from edge-intersections or can other points along the edge be used?

Comment: As you mentioned, you have tried. At stackoverflow we like to see code so we can help you, please add the code to your question.

Comment: @Aldert there is no need for the OP to provide an implementation of an entirely incorrect algorithm.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Interesting that you think you are the decision maker on this.

Comment: @Dave Yes any point along the edges can be used. Even points inside the polygon. Sorry, but maybe I have explained the problem poorly. Basically, the problem that I am facing is that I have an object in an image in the form of a binary mask. This object can be represented as a convex set. Now given this convex set I want to find the biggest isosceles (two equal sides) triangle that can fit into this convex set. My current approach is to try each tuple of points along the edges of the convex set in a brute-force manner, my question is whether there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @Aldert I also believe that it is a bit counterproductive to post incorrect algorithms. However, as ruakh mentioned I will remove that sentence from the question as it is just plainly wrong.

Comment: @KirillMeisser it can be proven that you'll never need an interior point, so there is exactly one isosceles triangle on each side of each pair of "base points".  Since your object is actually pixelated (image mask), maybe brute force isn't so bad?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks, brute force is not so bad but I was wondering if maybe there were some other ways. This processing would be done after a user interaction so my wish is to reduce the processing time to as low as possible for a better experience. I guess however this is as good as it is going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on the question, we know that that this is an algorithm that will be applied to a convex-shaped image mask after a user interaction.

This gives us a pretty good idea of how much time it can take and how big the input really is.  You have plenty of time for an algorithm that is O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the perimeter of the shape, because:

- The perimeter of a convex shape in an W x H image can be at most 2WH pixels.
- O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the perimeter of the shape is therefore O(n) in the size of the image.
- That's how long it takes to do *anything* that touches the whole image, and we do that kind of stuff after user interactions all the time.

So in your situation, it sounds like I would use a simple image processing algorithm like this:

1. Set point P1 anywhere on the perimeter, and walk it counter-clockwise all the way around the shape.
2. For each P1, start with P2 = P3 = P1, and walk P3 counter-clockwise all the way around the shape.
3. For each P1,P3 pair, advance P2 counter-clockwise until it crosses the perpendicular bisector of the P1-P3 line segment.  The 3 points now make an isosceles triangle and you can remember the one with the biggest area.

Since P2 moves more slowly than P3, P2 will advance less than 1 pixel on average for each P1,P3 pair in step 3, and this algorithm will take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time all together, where n is the number of pixels in the perimeter.